# Title: Dynamically Adding Total Amount to PayPal Payment Button from Booking Webpage

Tags: html, paypal

Description:

I'm developing a booking webpage where users can select various packages and book appointments. I'm integrating PayPal for payment processing. I want to dynamically calculate the total amount to be paid based on the user's total amount of adults  and kids that will be on the tour lets say for example each person cost 40 USD$ so it sums the total and update the PayPal payment button accordingly.

Here's what I have so far:

A booking webpage with various tours.
JavaScript functions to calculate the total amount based on the amount of people.
Now, I need guidance on how to dynamically update the total amount in the PayPal payment button. Specifically, I'm looking for assistance with:

Best practices for integrating PayPal payment buttons dynamically.
How to update the payment amount in the PayPal button dynamically using JavaScript.
Any potential pitfalls or considerations to keep in mind while implementing this functionality.
Any code examples, tutorials, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

ive tried various approach but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

A [standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) requires a backend to create and capture orders via API. JS is used for displaying buttons and obtaining approval from payers.